# Filter Prometheus metrics by label of another metric

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Let's say I have the following metrics:

```
system_cpu_usage{hostname="host1"} 10
system_cpu_usage{hostname="host2"} 92
system_cpu_usage{hostname="host3"} 95

process_cpu_usage{hostname="host2", cpu_usage="high"} 90
```

I have an alert condition as follows:

```
avg_over_time(system_cpu_usage[5m]) > 90
```

Which returns all instances where CPU usage is above 90:

```
system_cpu_usage{hostname="host2"} 92
system_cpu_usage{hostname="host3"} 95
```

But I would like to **exclude** instances which have the `process_cpu_usage{cpu_usage="high"}` metric present.

So, in that case it would just return:

```
system_cpu_usage{hostname="host3"} 95
```

Is this even possible using Prometheus/Grafana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out metrics based on the other metrics with [`unless`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) operator. It removes metrics from left-hand-side of this operator with same values of labels as those at the right-hand-side.

For example if you have metrics

```
metric1{label1="value1"}
metric1{label1="value2"}

metric2{label1="value1"}
```

expression

```
metric1 unless metric2
```

will return

```
metric1{label1="value2"}
```

For your exact case you'll additionally need to use [`on`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching-keywords) for label matching

```
avg_over_time(system_cpu_usage[5m]) > 90
 unless on(hostname) process_cpu_usage{cpu_usage="high"}
```